# Is resource_url from civicrm_settings.php saved in the civicrm_setting table, under what name?

Tags: civicrm-home

Where in civicrm_settings table is resource_url saved? I cannot use the System Settings/Resource URLs to set it, but can access the database.

Comment: Are you seeing the arrows in the menu? Or is civicrm broken? (I've seen problems with false positives on the warning about resource url being incorrect.)  The civicrm_root value should be set in your civicrm.settings.php.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing the database why not just override the value in the civicrm.settings.php file?

Check you have

```
global $civicrm_setting;
```

Then add
    $civicrm_setting['URL Preferences']['userFrameworkResourceURL'] = 'http://example.com/example-resource-url/';

More information here on this
https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/settings/

If you do want to update this directly in the database try the civicrm_setting table you want to search for a name of "userFrameworkResourceURL" and update the value column.

Best to make a back up of the database - or at the very least the table before changing it.

Alternatively you might also be able to set this via the api:

```
cv api Setting.create userFrameworkResourceURL="resource url here"
```

or

```
drush cvapi Setting.create userFrameworkResourceURL="resource url here"
```

depending on how broken your install is. Perhaps use Setting.get on dmaster via the api explorer to confirm what the appropriate format is:

https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/api3#explorer

Comment: thanks, Luke - the value is set in civicrm_settings, however it isn't reflected in Systems/Resource_urls. Someone make a change to the actual website url and havoc ensured. ..thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: It is set to civicrm_root in the  civicrm_setting table, just as it is shown in Resource_urls.